# GCC on windows No space left on device

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

When using GCC to compile a simple hello world program, I get the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: No space left on device
```

There is plenty of disk space and memory left. I am calling GCC from within the Git Bash command line. What is causing this problem and how do i fix it?

Using df shows:

```
$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
C:/Program Files/Git 975996924 171439984 804556940  18% /
I:                   260614460 219965568  40648892  85% /i
```

Comment: What does the `df` command show you? (I'm assuming Git Bash provides `df`.)

Comment: I can't add formatting to this comment. I will put that information in the main post.

Comment: Can you check your windows `%TEMP%` folder and the drive it is located on? if temporary drive is full, you can get this error too. Also try to add verbose flags to the linker with this switch and post the output: `-Wl,--verbose`

Comment: Where is the %TEMP% folder? How do I find its location?

Comment: in a DOS command: type `echo %TEMP%`

Comment: I deleted a 4K file in \AppData\Local\Temp and got the same gcc error

Comment: Did you check all permissions? You could also do a general disk check on top. What about all of the anti-virus software?

Comment: A 4K file is practically nothing.

Comment: I deleted some .png files and still nothing

Comment: try to add verbose flags to the linker with this switch and post the output: `gcc -o myexe.exe -Wl,--verbose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled GCC from the simple MinGW installer and installed the Codeblocks IDE. Codeblocks has an option to install the MinGW GCC. I do not understand what was wrong but this method works. The exact same command with the exact same C file compiles

Here is a simple video that shows the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3B4hPHZNtNw

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was running it on windows. It worked when I ran it with admin privileges. Try running it with sudo privileges:

```
sudo gcc file
```

If it still doesn't work, try changing the file permissions:

```
chmod 777 file
```

Hope this helps